# Echoing Variables within a JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to access and display a variable within a json object on my page. Can anyone tell me why the variable gets displayed three times?

my_array.php

```
<?php

$my_data=array(name=>"john",age=>"30", city=>"copenhagen");

// sending output
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode($my_data,true);
?>
```

My_page.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("my_array.php", function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key) {
        $("#showdata").append(data.city);
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>

//Show the data further down the page.

<div id="showdata"></div>
```

This displays

```
copenhagencopenhagencopenhagen
```

Comment: Its: `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: What do you want it to display?

Comment: Its displays three times because you have three keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're iterating over 'each' data item from the json response that you receive and there are 3 key=>value pairs in my_array.php

Removing "$.each(data, function(key) {} " will return the value 'city' only once

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.getJSON("my_array.php",function(data){
                $("#showdata").append(data.city);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

my_array.php

```
<?php

$my_data = array(
    name    =>  "john",
    age     =>  "30",
    city    =>  "copenhagen"
);

// sending output
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($my_data, true);

?>
```

My_page.php

```
<div id="showdata"></div>
<button>Click Me!</button>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e){
        $.getJSON("test.php", function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#showdata").append(data.city);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this will give you only one copenhagen.

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

Set either:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Above:

```
echo json_encode($my_data,true);
```

On your php file.

Or use the following snippet on your javascript:

```
$.getJSON("my_array.php",function(data)
{
  data=JSON.stringify(data);
  $.each(data, function(key) 
  {
    $("#showdata").append(data.city);
  });
});
```

Furthermore either in both ways above the returned data is an Object so in order to return correctly on your php file the data must be:

```
$my_data=array(array(name=>"john",age=>"30", city=>"copenhagen"));
```

Note: Associative arrays on php's json_encode turned into Objects. Non associative arrays on json_encode still remain an array

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing because you have got three buttons on  the page and the $.each takes the selector try:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("my_array.php",function(data){
    $("#showdata").append(data.city);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you're iterating 3 times because of the three keys you have within the JSON object,

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    console.log( "key + " " + val" );
  });
```

take a look at the JQuery documentation for further info.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/